# Определить минимальный из элементов массива с нечетными индексами

Tags: c#, .net

Элементы с нечетными индексами я нашел, но как определить минимальное из них? Код сам должен определять минимальное значение среди элементов с нечетным индексом. Явно определять элемент с минимальным значением нельзя.

```
class Data {
        static void Main() {

            int[] arrayONe = { 0, 1, 3, 9, 10, 4, 2, -4};

            // Шаг 1: Определить элементы с нечетными индексами

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayONe.Length; i++) {

                if (i % 2 != 0) {

                    Console.WriteLine("Значение элемента с нечетным индексом: " + arrayONe[i]);  

                }

            }


        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У `Where` есть [перегрузка с индексом](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549418(v=vs.110).aspx)!

Поэтому просто

```
arrayONe.Where((e, idx) => idx % 2 == 1).Min()
```

---

Ещё один вариант, на случай, если мы хотим воспользоваться доступом по индексу:

```
int from = 1, step = 2;
var max = Enumerable.Range(0, (arrayONe.Length - from + (step - 1)) / step)
                    .Min(idx => arrayONe[from + idx * step]);
```

(но вычисление длины фильтрованного списка в этом варианте кажется мне избыточно сложным).

Comment: Щас вам тоже палкой по пальцам надают за то что проходите по каждому элементу, а не только по нечетным!

Comment: @Андрей: На что я отвечу, что преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед.

Comment: @Андрей Главное -- объяснять минусы (для минусующих). И -- понимать код, который пишешь (для отвечающих).

Comment: @VladD только элемент нужен `Min` )

Comment: @sp7: Точно! Заменил, спасибо!

Comment: @VladD не могу победить вот эту часть `((e, idx) => idx % 2 == 1)`. Можете псевдокодом описать ?

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev: `Where` означает «выбрать только те элементы, для которых...». В `(e, idx)` `e` — значение элемента, `idx` — его индекс. Проверка `idx % 2 == 1` даёт `true` только если индекс нечётный. То есть мы отбираем только те элементы, у которых нечётный индекс. И по ним уже ищем минимум.

Comment: @AlekseyBudaev: (надеюсь, вы знакомы с лямбдами? это она и есть. если нет, срочно знакомьтесь!)

Comment: Ну вот, другое дело, первый хороший пример с Linq. :) Читабельный, простой и понятный, без лишнего выделения памяти и многократных проходов по циклу. Второй вариант не имеет смысла, в этом случае пишем for.

Comment: @LunarWhisper: Спасибо :)

Answer (score 4):

Да в общем-то как обычно: вводим переменную, которую сравниваем со всеми элементами в цикле.

```
void Main()
{
    int[] arrayONe = { 0, 1, 3, 9, 10, 4, 2, -4 };
    var firstMinElement = this.GetFirstEvenMinimumValue(arrayONe);
    Console.WriteLine(firstMinElement);
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public int GetFirstEvenMinimumValue(int[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length < 2)
        throw new Exception("Array is too short");

    var min = arr[1];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
            continue;

        if (arr[i] < min )
            min = arr[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

Кстати, действительно: можно ещё изящнее:

```
public int GetFirstEvenMinimumValue(int[] arr)
{
    if (arr.Length < 2)
        throw new Exception("Array is too short");

    var min = arr[1];

    for (int i = 3; i < arr.Length; i+=2)
    {
        if (arr[i] < min )
            min = arr[i];
    }

    return min;
}
```

(Вариант предложен @Lunar Whisper в комментариях)

Comment: Зачем проходить по каждому элементу массива и фильтровать по i % 2 != 0, если можно начать с 1го элемента и заменить инкемент на i += 2? :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper Отличное замечание, поправил. Действительно, незачем, просто писал код сильно не отвлекаясь от работы.

Comment: @AK `var min = arr[1]` вы сразу определяете элемент с индексом 1 как минимальное значение в массиве  ?

Comment: @AK Код сам должен определять минимальное значение среди элементов с нечетным индексом.

Comment: Если `var min = arr[1];`, то не проще ли потом `for (int i = 3; ...`?

Comment: @Alekcvp Думал. Лень было отлавливать случай вылета за границы массива arr[2]

Comment: @AK, а в C# цикл выполнится даже если стартовое значение изначально выходит за границы условия?..

Comment: @Alekcvp Точно. Поправил.

Answer (score 1):

```
var min = arrayONe
    .Select((s, i) => new { Index = i, Element = s})
    .Where(p => p.Index % 2 != 0) // Берем только нечетные элементы
    .Min(s => s.Element); // Получаем минимальный из них
```

Comment: Тоже написал бы так, но тут не уверен, что новичку будет понятен linq.

Comment: @AK а я то думаю к чему такие сложности )

Comment: А минус-то за что? Ответ верный, рабочий. Не нравится linq?

Comment: За избыточную вычислительную сложность на ровном месте, создание N ненужных экземпляров анонимного типа и итерирование по всему массиву, когда можно идти с шагом 2.

Comment: @sp7: Можно сэкономить немного памяти, если вместо анонимного типа использовать ValueTuple, оно структура. Но это мелкая оптимизация, конечно.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за замечание. Если честно я не сильно думал об оптимизации и лишних итерациях цикла. Просто это случай на мой взгляд не тот.

Comment: @sp7: Согласен, читаемость и корректность выше оптимизации (тем более в учебном примере!).